# NullPointer Error in android app

Tags: java, android

I have created an app that gets the date from the server and compares it to device's date and according to that displays notification.

It's working perfectly in India but when I uploaded the app to store and my client tested it, it's crashing. Still, I don't get any crashes in India. I have tried the clients username and password and still there is no crash. But Google play displays this crash report..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1324)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:536)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:821)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:376)
at com.myapp.common.CommonClass.getforCompare(CommonClass.java:535)
at com.myapp.ContractActivity$SyncronizeTask.doInBackground(ContractActivity.java:1029)
at com.myapp.ContractActivity$SyncronizeTask.doInBackground(ContractActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1183)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:518)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:818)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:307)
at myapp.common.CommonClass.getforCompare(CommonClass.java:535)
at myapp.ContractActivity$SyncronizeTask.doInBackground(ContractActivity.java:1029)
at com.manektech.contractnotify.ContractActivity$SyncronizeTask.doInBackground(ContractActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

I am confused. Why don't I get the crash or error and the client does?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/R1vpbGD6) is my code for activity.

Comment: may be this is locale problem, please try to use locale with simple date formatter

Comment: code for ContractActivity where you are formatting the date?

Comment: Show us the specific method in which this occurs.  This will help narrow down a cause.

Comment: I dont know the specific method but i can add code for the ContractActivity.

Comment: At this point, any sort of context would be helpful.  My hunch is that your `DateFormat` is returning `null`.

Comment: The only real hint I could see is `String tmpCompareDate = CommonClass.getforCompare(tmpExpirydate);`; it is likely the case that `tmpExpiryDate` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the locale in your phone settings to the locale that you suspect is set on the device, where the program is crashing. This way you may be able to reproduce the crash, making possible to debug.

Android version may also be problem, try on the emulator running version reported in the crash.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1324)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:536)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:821)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:376)
at com.myapp.common.CommonClass.getforCompare(CommonClass.java:535)
```

This says that there is a nullpointer exception in Calendar.setTime The chain includes CommonClass.java:535. Have a look at that code for null pointer possibilities.